# Save Filename to the database using laravel and mysql db

Tags: mysql, laravel, image

I create a File attachment for my request form, I want the file "name" save into the DB and the images will save to the storage but the problem is that neither of them is working. can you help me if I'm missing something in my code

```
        if($request->hasFile('filename'))
        {
            $path = storage_path('FirewallRequest/'.$firewall->fw_number);
            if(!File::exists($path)) {
                Storage::disk('fw_upload')->makeDirectory($firewall->fw_number);
            }
            $uploadcount = 0;
            while ($uploadcount < count($request->filename)) {
                $filename = $request->filename[$uploadcount];
                $fwupload = new ChangeManagementUploads;
                $fwupload->cm_number      =$firewall->fw_number;
                $fwupload->filename       =$filename->getClientOriginalName();
                $fwupload->request_type   =$request->xtype;
                $fwupload->save();
                Storage::disk('fw_upload')->put( '/'.$firewall->fw_number.'/'.$filename->getClientOriginalName(),File::get($filename));
                $uploadcount++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: why not use Spatie Media Library which is so efficient?

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/introduction

Comment: ow thank you for your suggestion khayam